# AttributeError: /src/libmi.so: undefined symbol: logarithm

Tags: python, c++, dll, dllimport

I've tried to call function on C/C++ from python3 code and get the error from header. Earlier this C/C++ function could be imported in ppython works, but I forget how it was done.

C/C++ function:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" double logarithm(unsigned a)
#else
double logarithm(unsigned a)
#endif
{
    if (a != 0)
    {
        return log2(a);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Python code:

```
import os 
from ctypes import *
libname = os.path.abspath("/src/libmi.so")
mi = CDLL(libname)
mi.logarithm.restype = c_double
```

Full text of exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 5>()
      3 libname = os.path.abspath("/src/libmi.so")
      4 mi = CDLL(libname)
----> 5 mi.logarithm.restype = c_double

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py:386, in CDLL.__getattr__(self, name)
    384 if name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__'):
    385     raise AttributeError(name)
--> 386 func = self.__getitem__(name)
    387 setattr(self, name, func)
    388 return func

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py:391, in CDLL.__getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal)
    390 def __getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal):
--> 391     func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
    392     if not isinstance(name_or_ordinal, int):
    393         func.__name__ = name_or_ordinal

AttributeError: /src/libmi.so: undefined symbol: logarithm
```

The commands for builder and linker:

```
g++ -fPIC -c $(python3.8-config  --includes) -o mi.o mi.cpp
g++ $(python3.8-config --ldflags) -lpython3.8  mi.o -o libmi.so
```

I have checked the symbol link in libmi.so:

```
root@5c574a48a4ce:/src#  objdump -t libmi.so | grep logarithm
0000000000001225 g     F .text  0000000000000034              logarithm
```

How it can be solved?

Comment: Is there a `-shared` missing when linking?

Comment: thank you, @MSpiller, this was the reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MSpiller commented, the right linker's command is

```
g++ $(python3.8-config --ldflags) -lpython3.8 -shared mi.o -o libmi.so
```